# Time Machine backup failing

Tags: backup

My Time Machine backups starting failing a couple weeks ago. In my Console System Log, during the entire time it's backing up I have continuous entries like this:

com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.0E000000-0200-0000-0000-000000000000[1524]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[194]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly, not much as I wasn't sure what to try.  Obviously I rebooted. I did an NVRAM reset and I tried a different USB port for my drive. I also did a disk repair on that drive.

Comment: Today I tried disconnecting a couple external hard drives that time machine was  backing up and the backup didn't crash this time, but it's been stuck on Cleaning up for about 5 hours now.

Comment: This is the kind of task I'd give to [DiskWarrior](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/), shame it can only fix HFS, not APFS yet, but it's good for Time Machine drives.. Either that or wipe it & start over.

Comment: Yeah, I'm about to the point where I'm going to wipe it. I have my photos library on an external SSD and that appears to be where it's failing. We've probably screwed up by not splitting the library at some point because right now it's sitting at 980GB but that's a story for another day.